# Parsing lircd.conf using javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, client, lirc

How can I parse lircd.conf files from LIRC database (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/p/lirc-remotes/code/ci/master/tree/remotes/yamaha/RX-V850.lircd.conf) for use in my javascript project?

I'd prefer a parser in javascript that can run in client browser.

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: No, I have never used javascript for parsing.
I found one using python (https://github.com/slimjim777/web-irsend/blob/master/lirc/lirc.py), looking for a good starting point using javascript.